# Rotate the fill pattern with the shape in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving tiles of the pattern in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65268/moving-tiles-of-the-pattern-in-tikz)

I have a rotated rectangle filled with a pattern, and I would like to also rotate the pattern by the same amount.

In this MWE, the second `node` is a rotated `rectangle`, but its `north east lines` `pattern` is parallel to the first `node`'s `pattern`.

[image: Straight and rotated rectangles]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, minimum size=0.5cm, rectangle, pattern=north east lines] at (0,0) {};
  \node[draw, minimum size=0.5cm, rectangle, pattern=north east lines, rotate=30] at (1cm,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not easy, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65270/86. In fact the answer is the same. Even `transform canvas` can not be used.

Comment: I didn't know that, I would have expected `transform canvas` to work (despite causing all sorts of other problems). I guess I should manually draw the pattern then. You can make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am trying to make it a duplicate. The answer provided in the linked question should suffice (no need for point spamming ;) ) Thank you! :)