# how to transform a pattern in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to be able to transform tikz's predefined patterns.
To make things concrete, how should I modify the following code to get the checkerboard pattern to be slanted along with the rectangle?

```
\draw[pattern=checkerboard light gray,yslant=-.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
```

This question arose in the following context: In a 3D-picture, I would like to fill paths *in the coordinate planes* with the checkerboard pattern slanted in the way the coordinate plane is through the perspective defined by my coordinate redefinitions, e.g.,

```
z={(-.7,-.3)},x={(.9,-.1)}
```

Comment: I think that it is not possible. Read this [possibly related answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65268/moving-tiles-of-the-pattern-in-tikz/65270#65270)

Comment: @JLDiaz: Wouldn't canvas transformations be applicable? (I tried it, but didn't get it to work.)

Comment: I've closed as a dupe: looks close to me. I think the issue with a canvas op would be that `pgf` will deliberately avoid passing one through, so you'd have to 'step output' and use a raw driver transform.