# How can TikZ patterns be programmatically aligned for all shapes which use a pattern?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

Very similar to [Correcting TikZ pattern offsets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545820/correcting-tikz-pattern-offsets) but I couldn't figure out how to do this programmatically.

Specifically, I have some nodes I'd like to use arbitrarily in text, formulae, figures, whatever, which are patterned, and I'd like them all to look the same.

Something similar to this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,patterns,patterns.meta}

\newcommand{\dotnode}[1]{
  \zsavepos{#1}
  \tikz[baseline = -0.5ex]{\node[state,
                                 rectangle,
                                 pattern={Dots[xshift={\zposx{#1} sp}, yshift={\zposy{#1} sp}, angle=45, distance={4pt}, radius=0.6pt]},
                                 minimum size=10pt]{}}
  at (\zposx{#1}, \zposy{#1})}


\begin{document}
This is a \dotnode{1} and this is another \dotnode{2}.
\lipsum[1]
This is another \dotnode{3}.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,5}
{
     \node [rectangle,draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,
     pattern={Dots[xshift={1.1*\n cm}]}] at (1.1*\n cm, 1.1) {};   
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: PDF produced by MWE]

Clearly, the dotted boxes in the text do not look the same (the bottom, good, row is from the code in the link at the top of this question).

My attempt was to use `\zsavepos` and use that position to `xshift`/`yshift`, and if it worked I could make the tag generation automatic, but it clearly failed. I'm not sure I understand `\zsavepos` correctly because the y-coordinate is the same for the first two nodes in the image, when one is clearly higher than the other (I assume the printing of `\zposx`/`y` "pushed" it?). I'm also concerned that `\zsavepos` would give me trouble in double column layouts which is what I am working with.

Comment: This seems like a lot of effort.  You can adjust the baseline of a tikzpicture using the [baseline=(anchor)] option and [outer xsep=...] to adjust the spacing around a node.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Oh that's a shame to hear. Then I might look into using SVGs or whether TikZ supports SVG/PNG/PDF/... backgrounds for nodes. Thanks for `outer`, I did not know about it.

Comment: You could overlap two nodes, one with \includegrphics and one with a pattern with a transparent background.